# Y a-t-il une différence entre « pillard » et « pilleur » ?

Tags: sens, usage, synonymes, origine-ou-raison, suffixes

> *Des pilleurs sévissent après le passage de l'ouragan Idalia.* (titre
> ds. [LaPresse](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/2023-09-02/floride/des-pilleurs-sevissent-apres-le-passage-de-l-ouragan-idalia.php))

Que ce soit *pilleur* ou *pillard*, il s'agit d'une « personne qui se livre au [pillage](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pillage) » (TLFi : [*pilleur*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pilleur), [*pillard*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pillard)).

Y a-t-il une nuance de sens, d'emploi, de registre ou autrement entre ces deux mots ; peut-on brièvement comparer le sens de leur suffixation ([-ard](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ard), [-eur](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-eur)) ou leur origine : est-ce que ça change quoi que ce soit à la première partie de la réponse ?

Answer (score 5):

> En général, *pillard* s'utilise seul, tandis que *pilleur* accepte les
> compléments (pilleur de tombe, d'épave, de troncs, de banques, ...).
> Cela me semble être la seule nuance entre ces 2 synonymes.
> ([Graffito](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53616/y-a-t-il-une-diff%C3%A9rence-entre-pillard-et-pilleur#comment114071_53616))

Comment: Je dirais même que pilleur ne s'utilise qu'avec un complément, non ?

Answer (score 5):

Dans mon ressenti, il y a une différence subtile: quand on parle de "pilleur" on part d'un acte de pillage et on remonte à l'auteur de cet acte, alors que quand on parle de "pillard" on part d'une personne et on l'essentialise.

> Ces barbares ne sont que des pillards, ils ne produisent rien par eux-même !

> On n'a à ce jour toujours pas identifié les pilleurs de la station-service de XXXXXX.